# Adding extra data to shortcode attributes and pass it to JS with wp_localize_script

Tags: php, functions, javascript

I wanted to add extra data to shortcode attributes array and pass the array to js with wp_localize_script, the data is added and the array is sent, but it's also printed as :

```
<script>var custom = {"status":"new","type":"depend","url":"https:\/\/www.exemple.com"};</script>
```

My code in functions.php :

```
function resources() {
    wp_register_script('custom_js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/assets/js/custom.js', array('jquery'), '', TRUE);
    wp_register_style( 'custom_css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/custom.css', array(), '1', 'all' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'resources' );

function new_shortcode($atts){

    if (!empty($atts)) {
        $atts['url'] = MAIN_URL;
        wp_localize_script('custom_js', 'custom', $atts);
    }
    wp_enqueue_script("custom_js");
    wp_enqueue_style("custom_css");

}
add_shortcode('custom', 'new_shortcode');
```

Is there another way to do this without printing the data in script tag ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. It looks like everything is working as expected. That's how `wp_localize_script()` works. It prints a script tag that assigns the values to a global variable that you can access from your script.

Comment: Thank you for replying me, I want to send the data to js file "custom_js" to handle it without printing it in html <script></script>

Comment: Well you can't. There has to be JS somewhere that's putting your data into a variable, so it's always going to be accessible. I don't see what the problem with the data being in the HTML

Comment: Probably because if you remove that line there's nothing to output.

Comment: is there another way to send shortcode attributes to js file without printing it ?

Comment: No. Think about how you access data in JS. To access it the data needs to be in a variable, and to put data into the variable you need a script that does this. The only 2 places for a script are a file or inline, and when shortcode data is parsed during render the only option to output it is to print an inline script.

Answer (score 0):

> First, Thank you Jacob Peattie for your help.

I decided to solve this issue partly (the data being easily readable) with encoding the data using base64_encode() & json_encode() in php and decoding it in javascript with JSON.parse() & atob().